# Material on Android 4.4

Tags: java, android, material-design

I am developing my app with Android Studio 2.3.3 and any element is in material design on Android 7 but if run application on Android 4.4 element change position and style.

[image: Constraint Layout]

Run on 7.1.1

[image]

Run on 4.4

[image]

I know that **Android 4 does not support the Material design** except with third-party items but I would like to understand why the position changes.

Any idea or fix?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        tools:context="com.scannerproject.MainActivity"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="243dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:onClick="scan"
        android:text="SCANSIONE"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.457" />    

    <Switch
            android:id="@+id/flash"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Attiva Flash"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/button"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.555" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please provide the code you are working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little fix, point the right toggle with the right button

[image]